# Access other fields in Request to FastAPI when uploading file using POST method

Tags: python, client-server, fastapi

I have a server running FastAPI code which looks something like this

```
@app.post('/upload/')
def post_file(req: Request, file: UploadFile=File(...)):
:
:
```

On the client side I am POSTing my file as follows

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart import encoder
:
:
s = requests.Session()
with open(myfile, 'rb') as fd:
    fr = encoder.MultipartEncoder(
        {'file': (myfile, fd, 'application/octet-stream'),
         'other_field' : json.dumps(list_of_other_files)})
    s.headers.update(
        {"Prefer": "respond-async", "Content-Type": fr.content_type}
    )
    resp = s.post(my_url, data=fr, allow_redirects=False)
```

The POST goes through and can access the file using "file" object at the server, I want to know how do I also access 'other_field' when processing this POST request.

I tried using req.body() and req.json() but didnt work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does `other_field: str = Form(...)` in the view function signature work (in addition to `file: ..`)? That's how you'd usually include form fields.

Comment: @MatsLindh: Thank you very much. It worked that way.